# How to install Wireless Driver from Windows Update with error 80070002?

Tags: windows, windows-8, installation, drivers, windows-update

I am experiencing problems with installing simple WLAN driver for System: **Windows 8 64bit**. Wireless card is: **Qualcomm Atheros AR9285**. I tried to install driver manualy even from Windows Update but it always says error: **0x80070002 = ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND**

I tried to use these commands:

**DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-image /Scanhealth**

**DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-image /Restorehealth**

To somehow restore my Windows Update program but nothing has worked so far. I also installed Process monitor program and recorded files changes during driver updates and here is result: http://postimage.org/image/deaneocfb/ (double click for full resolution)

I tried to install drivers old, new, exe, non-exe drivers manualy in system hardware and still the same error has occured - file not found and yet driver package seems to be complete so what is missing and where?

I hope someone can help how to install driver for this and somehow workaround this error? Thank you.

Comment: upload the file "C:\Windows\inf\setupapi.dev.log", please.

Comment: http://www60.zippyshare.com/v/52518371/file.html Here it is

Comment: you use version 3.0.0.119, try the version 10.0.0.212. Use IE to download the driver from here: http://catalog.update.microsoft.com/v7/site/ScopedViewInline.aspx?updateid=82d31593-1ec0-42c1-853a-2d6e816f186c Extract the CAB and use device manager to install the driver.

Comment: I managed to download the Cab file - extracted it - tried to install with device manager - and still the same error as before: Driver for the device was found but there was an error: System cannot find the file. Version 3.x is maybe the last which i managed to install but I tried 9.x even 10.x like this driver here http://www67.zippyshare.com/v/23722201/file.html and still got the same error about "some file" not found... So can I know which file is missing where? Maybe some prmission problem in Windows 8 which cannot crate driver file or anythig? I am just shooting in the dark ...

Comment: upload the new log and not the driver.

Comment: What log exactly? I cannot install any driver now still error about file not found and still the driver is full (all files there)

Comment: I need the new setupapi log which contains the install failure of the 10.0.0.212 driver

Comment: Here it is http://paste2.org/p/2981560

Comment: ok, added the "Wireless Hosted Network" (virtual WIFi) feature fails:  ´Add Service: Failed to modify existing service 'vwifibus'` this seams to cause the error.

Run **sfc /scannow** and look if this fixes issues.

Comment: Still the same no change at all even after restart...

Comment: look if the system has writing permissions to the registry key "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\vwifibus"

Comment: There is a screen http://postimage.org/image/4esk82aob/ (parameters folder is empty)

Comment: make a rightlick on the vwifibus key and select "permissions". Make sure that **SYSTEM** and admins have full access.

Comment: Yes both admin and system have full access to this in regedit ...

Comment: I have no idea. Use the good old inplace upgrade/Repair install to repair Windows: http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/3413-repair-install.html

Comment: Hmm strange ... is it possible to do this in Windows 8 without installation CD? As I upgraded only without it.

Comment: download your ISO from MS with your upgrade key: http://www.intowindows.com/download-windows-8-iso-from-microsoft-using-product-key/

Comment: This did not help either! Is there a way I disabled by accident some sturtup process which is needed for this? I think my friend did something in proceses.msc so which processes are needed for successful install of this driver?

Comment: I have no idea. Backup all data and reinstall Windows completely.